# Child process does not terminate

Tags: c, process

this line of code executes perfectly fine for the most of the time, but for very specific occasions, the child process does not terminate (though it prints the right outputs) and the control is not given back to its parent.. what may be the issue here?

```c
void execute(char *path, char *argv[])
{
    if(!path)
    {
        return;
    }
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    //child process execution
    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        print_error();
        return;
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        print_error();
        exit(0);   

    }

    wait(&status);
    return;  
}
```

[Ive attatched the screen shot of my terminal for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhDta.png)

Comment: Screenshots are not readable on mobile devices. You've not shown what you are executing.  You should return a non-zero status when you fail to execute the command.

Comment: the contents in my argv[] was {ls,-l,NULL,NULL,NULL....}.

Comment: The problem is that it does execute the command, which I can see as a. standard output, but does not give control back to its parent. If I run it on gdb, I can see that the wait command is not invoked. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that wait() does not return? What is supposed to happen after your execute() function returns?

Comment: yep I tried using gdb to check that, and set a break on wait. It didn't seem to work, it doesn't even print out the prompts or exits, before I force quit the entire program using ctrl c.. It is supposed to continue executing other commands in the main function--specifically it is supposed to execute the while loop